# EnhancedSeatMap Seat Without Price

Tags: sabre

I am having some trouble with `EnhancedSeatMapRQ`, as the seats for certain airlines (e.g. AC, AA, etc.) do not return any `BasePrice` or `Price` node. When checked with Sabre software, some of these seats **do have a cost charged upon booking**.

My understanding is in these situations, the `CommercialName` value is supposed to help lookup the price. With that said, there is no reference in the response that indicates any price, for anything.

Here is one with a price node:

```xml
<Offer entitledInd="false">
    <CommercialName>SEAT ASSIGNMENT</CommercialName>
    <BasePrice>
      <TotalAmount currencyCode="CAD">27.12</TotalAmount>
      <Taxes>
        <Tax currencyCode="CAD">3.12</Tax>
        <TaxTypeRef>taxTypeDetail_1</TaxTypeRef>
      </Taxes>
    </BasePrice>
</Offer>
```

And one without it:

```xml
 <Offer entitledInd="true">
  <CommercialName>ADVANCE SEAT SELECTION</CommercialName>
  <OfferItemId>offerItem_1</OfferItemId>
  <TravellerID>1</TravellerID>
</Offer>
```

`Specifies the commercial name associated with matched price.` is all that the docs say about the `CommercialName` node.

Please guide me through the process of pricing these seats, as it's crucial to a proper seat selection process.

UPDATE: We have noticed that all the `Offer` nodes without a `Price` or `BasePrice`, are inside seats with `chargeableInd` set to `false`. With that said, this happens with a significant number of the Airlines, and if unresolved, will render our seat selection counter-productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Sabre team got back to me, and clarified the issue.
When sending a `SeatMapQueryEnhanced`, the `/CabinDefinition/RBD` is supposed to have the `@ProgramSystemCode`, received from BFM.

Example:

```
 <Flight origin="YVR" destination="DFW">
     <DepartureDate>2022-07-13</DepartureDate>
         <Operating carrier="AA">392</Operating>
             <Marketing carrier="AA">392</Marketing>
         <ArrivalDate>2022-07-13</ArrivalDate>
 </Flight>
 <CabinDefinition>
     <RBD>N</RBD>
 </CabinDefinition>
```

Where N is extracted form the `ProgramSystemCode` attribute of that `Segment` node.